# query GROUP EACH BY explodes

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running the following query on 128GB table with 220 million rows:

```
select id, count(*) as cnt 
from logs.nobids_05 
group each by 1 
having cnt > 1 
limit 10;
```

It fails with "Resources exceeded during query execution" error.

id are in this table should be unique and I would like to check if it's indeed the case.

Is there a way to run this query?

I understand that the algorithm behind should probably produce a temporary hash table similar in size to the original table. Does bigquery (dremel) still has limitation on the amount of temporary data it can create per query?

do you have a suggestion for workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed. You should no longer see resources exceeded for this query, and many other queries should no longer hit this issue. Please ping the thread if you continue to have problems.

Background:

When you use GROUP EACH BY, BigQuery makes a guess about the size of data that will be involved in the GROUP EACH BY operation (technically, it cares about the cardinality of the keys). Sometimes this is easy, sometimes it is not.

The configuration thresholds for this had been  set too small; that is, for a given query, we weren't giving it enough resources for the GROUP EACH BY operation to succeed.

Comment: Unfortunately adding destination table and setting allow_large_results did not help. I succeeded to verify whether we have only distinct values by running "SELECT count(distinct id) - count(id) FROM .." query. It returned large non-zero number so I still need the original query in order to debug duplicates.

Comment: Guys, did you consider exposing a minimal interface for mapreduce?
Even some sort of python interface with mapper receiving protobuf object (according to the GC schema) and reducer outputting to GCS would be really helpful.

Comment: We've rolled out a fix, please try again.

Comment: Btw, BigQuery has a connector for Hadoop and other clients that might benefit from sharded access to the data: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/04/google-bigquery-and-datastore-connectors-for-hadoop.html